# SOAPUI REST url having + in JSON issue

Tags: url, soapui

I am using SOAPUI v4.6.4.

I am testing REST SOAPUI test. I have the media type set to application/json.

I am trying to pass this value as part of JSON string and I get 404 server error.

**{"enteredTime":"2001-12-17T09:30:47+05:00"}**

It is having issues with **+** sign.

I tried encoding it as **2001-12-17T09%3A30%3A47%2B05%3A00**. The 404 server is gone but the application code is **NOT** expecting the encoded value.

Any solutions are highly appreciated.

Comment: How do you set the encoding? Is it via the TestRequest Encoding setting?

Comment: Is this the body of a POST, or the URL of a PUT/GET? If it is the body of a POST, that does not get encoded.